# How to display the name of the weekdays?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

This is what I had tried:

```
dates = pd.date_range('10-01-2016', periods=9, freq='2W-SUN')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Count 1': 100 + np.random.randint(-5, 10, 9).cumsum(),
                  'Count 2': 120 + np.random.randint(-5, 10, 9)}, index=dates)
df
```

To display weekday name:

```
df.index.weekday_name
```

But I've got

```
 AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'weekday_name'
```

Expected output:

```
Index(['Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday',
       'Sunday', 'Sunday'],
      dtype='object')
```

Help me to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is `day_name`

Comment: Use `df.index.day_name()`

Comment: <bound method inherit_from_data.<locals>.method of DatetimeIndex(['2016-10-02', '2016-10-16', '2016-10-30', '2016-11-13',
               '2016-11-27', '2016-12-11', '2016-12-25', '2017-01-08',
               '2017-01-22'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='2W-SUN')>

Comment: Not getting expected output

Comment: There missing `()`

Comment: `df.index.day_name()`